# Assign instance of a class to an attribbute of a bigger class for creating nested dot notation

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Some times I found useful split bigger class in smaller classes with their methods and attributes that then I access assigning to an attribute of the bigger class an instance of the smaller class. In this way I can organize the class better: when I work using the console I can use nested dot notation instead of seeing a lot of attributes. For instance, I have an instrument with some parameters that can be grouped together and a method that is linked to these parameters. I would structure the class like this:

```
class params(object):
    def __init__(self,P,I,D):
        self.P = P
        self.I = I
        self.D = D

    def compute_PID(self):
        pass

class instrument(object):
    def __init__(self,name,SN,P,I,D):
        self.name = name
        self.SN = SN
        self.params = params(P,I,D)

     def swith_on(self):
        pass

myinstrument = instrument('blender','123',45,4,3)
myinstrument.params.P
```

Is there any drawback of this deign patter? I imagine that from the point of view of the memory it requires more memory, but working with the dot notation make the things easier compared to a dictionary.

Comment: I don't see nothing bad with your approach, that's a simple composition

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I didn't know it was called like that